# Remove additional processes/services from Ubuntu server

Tags: server, performance

I just installed PostgreSQL 9.1 and its packages: 'postgis and pgadmin' on Ubuntu Server 13.10.

Now I'd like to remove any other processes/services on the server in order to improve its performance.. what is the most safe way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Install rcconf:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
```

And then run it with root privileges:

```
sudo rcconf
```

What I usually do is disable postgres and start it manually when I need it (I'm only using for my course of database management, so I don't need it running all the time).

```
sudo service postgresql-9.1 start
sudo service postgresql-9.1 stop
```